# How to exclude file extension from string with regex

Tags: regex

I want to be able to get two matching groups from a regex and exclude a third.
This is an example of a string I want to match:

```
my-file-name-0.44.0.6-SOME-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

I want two matching groups, one for the file name without the version and one for the version without the file extension.

- Group 1: my-file-name
- Group 2: 0.44.0.6-SOME-SNAPSHOT
- Excluded: .zip

the file name can be random, but the version will always have a hyphen before it, then file extension can also be random.

This is what I have come up with, but can't figure out the exclude part.

```
(.*?)-([0-9.]{1,4}.*)
```

Comment: `([\w-]+)-([\d.]+[\w-]+)(\.\w+)`?

Comment: `^(.*?)-([0-9.]{1,4}.*)(\..+?)$`

Comment: Your examples have 3 groups, only want the 2 first, might this work?
(.*?)-(\d.+.*)\..+?$

Comment: The rules you described are not enough for unique identification of the file name and version. `my` as file name and `file-name-0.44.0.6-SOME-SNAPSHOT` as version match the rules. The same for (`my-file` and `name-0.44`) or (`my-file-name` and `0.44`).

Comment: The file name will always have two parts divided by "-" followed by the file extension. This is will be used in a tool where I can define a regexp, so can't do it by using code.

Comment: `([^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*)-(.*)\..*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `\.` to your regex:

```
(.*?)-([0-9.]{1,4}.*)\.
```

However you may want to modify it a little:

```
(.*?)-(\d.*)\.\w+
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uiT58G/3)

Answer (score -1):

Use this regular expression to **remove file extension**:

```
/(.*)\.[^.]+$/
```

Comment: This only gives me one group for the whole file name including the version part.